# Formatting JavaScript Output Horizontally Instead of Vertical List

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I format this object output to be horizontally listed instead of vertical?

```
for(var i=0; i<a; i++){
$('#{STORIES.story_id}6').append($('<div>', {text: sound[i].title}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so much a JavaScript question than it is a HTML/CSS question.
The output is vertical is most likely due to the use of `<div>` tag. It is a *block* level element, therefore there will always be space before and after this element.  (Read more about `block` vs `inline` here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/ )

Try using an *inline* element. Eg. `<span>`

Keep in mind that in order to be valid markup, any `inline` level element must be contained in a `block` level element. *Edit:* To clarify, you can't have a `block` level element inside an `inline` level element.

Comment: Why? An in-line element (such as a `span`) can appear within another in-line element, such as a `span`, or an `a`.

Comment: An inline element can be in an inline element. That's fine, but one of its ancestors must be a `block` element. The good news is that `<body>` and `<html>` are both `block` level.